# How to implement BehaviorSubject to reflect changes in 2 components?

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have a service and 2 components. When I switch case switches to submit, I want to send text - 'received' to the second component, then the second component gets the message, I want to alert that message and send different text message - 'done' to the first component:

```
private message = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
messageText = this.message.asObservable();
sendMessage(text: any) {
   this.message.next(text);
 }
```

component one:

```
ngOnInit() {
text: string = '';
this.mainService.enableBtn.subscribe(message=> {
this.text = message
    })
}
```

component two:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.mainService.enableBtn.subscribe(message=> {
alert(message)
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have recreated a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gr2ucg) with what you're requesting.

Basically you would have to either use two objects of type BehaviorSubject and deal with each for a component, or you could use just one, and have the generic type to be a Map.
My implementetion is the latter, mainly because that can be used for unlimited number of components, as long as you have a good way of identifying the components (here I'm using hard strings for ease of use, but I wouldn't recommend that on a real project).

It really depends on what you want to accomplish though. I have made this more as an example, so you can see better how the whole flow works in isolation.

Hope that helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If this resolved your question @zana10, consider marking it as your answer to close the question. Thanks!